# Mocking EntityManagerFactory when 2 Datasources are defined

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, mockito

So, my application is connected to 2 Mysql DBs.
Since I added support for 2 Dbs, my Mockito test ends up with this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to register mock bean javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory expected a single matching bean to replace but found [myCustomEntityManager1, myCustomerEntityManager2]
```

This is how it's currently declared

```
@MockBean
private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
```

And this is how I declared the custom entityManager:

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean myCustomEntityManager1() {
    return entityManagerConfiguration.getEntityManager(MY_PACKAGE, getDatasource());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@MockBean takes [name](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/MockBean.html#name--) attribute which allows you to specify the name of the bean to register or replace.

In your case:

```
@MockBean(name="myCustomEntityManager1")
private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
```

You may also want to [give your bean a more descriptive name](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html).

> While a name() attribute is available, the default strategy for determining the name of a bean is to use the name of the @Bean method. This is convenient and intuitive, but if explicit naming is desired, the name attribute (or its alias value) may be used. Also note that name accepts an array of Strings, allowing for multiple names (i.e. a primary bean name plus one or more aliases) for a single bean.